# Nodemailer timeout with heroku-22 stack

Tags: heroku, timeout, nodemailer

I upgraded the stack of my heroku app from heroku-20 to heroku-22. After this upgrade, all the requests which send a mail using nodemailer end up in an H12 timeout error (after 30s). However, when I downgrade back to heroku-20 everything is working fine (the request is made within 2s). Does anyone else experience this issue and how did you solve it? Thanks already!

Comment: Did you discover what was going on?

Comment: @LittleFish Unfortunately no. I stayed with the old heroku stack and have now moved away from heroku completely.